# New lines after grep a binary file are missing

Tags: extract, grep

Im trying to get text from text layers in a PSD file, under linux.

Now Im using:

```
egrep -a 'LayerText' file.psd

<photoshop:LayerText>免费获得宝贵资源! \ 工业现场过程仪表校准测试和维护诊断的必备工具 福禄克过程校准器，为工作在过程行业的技术工程师，自动化系统维护和仪表工程师，质量控制工程师，计量人员提供全面的工业校准测试和维护诊断工具：包括智能认证校准器，多功能信号校准器，压力校准器，温度校准器，环路校准器以及其他过程信号故障诊断和检测工具。FLUKE过程校准及检测工具，在化工、电力、石油、纸浆、食品饮料、制造业和污水处 理/给排水等行业的现场校准及检测维护方面处于世界领先水平。过程校准的全系列产品，从简单的回路校准器到复杂的文档化全功能过程校准器，可以提供各种必需的温度、压力、电流、电压以及电阻和频率的校准。来自福禄克750系列的校准管理软件，更是满足了用户 日益增长的对现场仪表校准数据进行归档整理的需求</photoshop:LayerText>
```

But using Photoshop the text layer has new lines after:

```
免费获得宝贵资源!
工业现场过程仪表校准测试和维护诊断的必备工具
```

How can I parse and output the text separated by real newlines and not all in one single line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your file does not contain a regular newline character but something else (looks like two spaces around a backslash).

If you want to separate the files using this (which looks like unusual) line separator, you can do that e.g. using sed(1).

Comment: Yes I noticed that, is unusual, and after 工业现场过程仪表校准测试和维护诊断的必备工具 theres no space \ space